# How can I implement a map with different data types as values?

Tags: c++, dictionary, polymorphism, stdmap

I want to put two (not more) different data types as values into a map as shown in the following example:

```
typeX A, B, ...;
typeY Z, Y, ...;

void func (typeX) { ... }
void func (typeY) { ... }

std::map <std::string, what_to_put_here??> map;
map["a"] = A;
map["z"] = Z;
...

std::vector<std::string> list;
// This list will be something like "a", "y", ...

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i)
    func( map[list[i]] )
```

Obviously this doesn't work, as the map will only accept one data type of value. However, when looping over `list`, the call to `func()` should be unambiguous since the type of `map[list[i]]` is known.

I want to avoid explicit casting or type checking, i.e. something like this:

```
if (typeid( map[list[i]] ).name() == "typeX")
    func( map[list[i]] )
else if (typeid( map[list[i]] ).name() == "typeY")
    func( map[list[i]] )
```

Is this possible? Again, it will be limited to only two different data types.

Comment: I would make wrapper class with two member variables and use it in map declaration.

Comment: [boost::variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost/variant.html) might help.

Comment: Have you considered making `typeX` and `typeY` subclasses of a common base class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/variant.html):

```
std::map <std::string, boost::variant<typeX, typeY>>
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried to use that but it gives me an error at the func( map[list[i]] ), since func() does apparently not accept boost::var. Do I have to explicitly typecheck?

Comment: You must explicitly extract the object to its correct type before you can call `func`

Answer (score 2):

Are typeX and typeY subclasses of a typeBase class ?
If so, you could do a `std::map<std::string,typeBase*>` to store both typeX* and typeY* in the map.

Answer (score 1):

With some metaprogramming you can easily build an heterogenous map which can store any type from a given set of types. [Here is an example](http://libclaw.sourceforge.net/multi_type_map.html) which does this, without type erasure nor the need to visit the values.

Answer (score 1):

One way to implement a multi-type map is by using the nifty features of std::tuple in C++11, which allows access by a type key. You can wrap this to create access by arbitrary keys. An in-depth explanation of this (and quite an interesting read) is available here:

https://jguegant.github.io/blogs/tech/thread-safe-multi-type-map.html

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use [Boost](https://www.boost.org/), then I think building a class hierarchy as [proposed by rom1504](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21385166/2675154) makes sense. I would implement an [abstract base class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/abstract_class) with `func()` as member function as follows:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void func() = 0;
};

void Base::func() {};
```

Then, I would turn your `typeX` and `typeY` data types into subclasses by deriving from `Base` as follows:

```
class typeX : public Base {
public:
    void func() { std::cout << "typeX::func()" << std::endl; };
    int i;  // Example for your original 'typeX' content.
};

class typeY : public Base {
public:
    void func() { std::cout << "typeY::func()" << std::endl; };
    std::string s;  // Example for your original 'typeY' content.
};
```

Here, the `func()` implementations would take the content of your corresponding global `func()` functions. Next, your map needs to store pointers to `Base` as value:

```
std::map<std::string, Base*> map;
map["a"] = &A;
map["z"] = &Z;
```

As a result, you can implement your loop as follows (using a [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) [range-based `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)):

```
for (auto const &list_item : list)
    map[list_item]->func();
```

Notes:

- In case you use dynamically created instances of `typeX` and `typeY`, you should prefer to store [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) in the map, such as [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr), to ease memory management.
- If you have to stick to your global `func()` functions, then you can call them from the corresponding member functions. I would just turn the parameter into a pointer or reference to avoid copying objects.

[Full code on Ideone](https://ideone.com/U13IDn)

Answer (score 0):

This would probably be extreme overkill, but QT has a variable called QVariant which can be used to map to different types of (QT) variables.

Documentation here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qvariant.html

Answer (score 0):

You need a [type erasure](http://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2013/11/18/type-erasure-part-i/).

[Type erasure](http://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2013/11/18/type-erasure-part-i/) is a pattern that hides the underlying type, such known examples are [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/any.html), but keep in mind that boost any has a dynamic polymorphic behavior (dynamic dispatch at runtime). boost::variant on the other hand is another example and uses template metaprogramming techniques. see [variant vs any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/variant/misc.html#variant.versus-any)

The simplest solution though, could be writing your own class type erasure with an enum for the underlying type.