How can I create a map which can hold mapped values of two different types?
I need to make a std::map for topic names (std::string) and msgs of ros2. How do I declare the std::map, i.e., ref_maps?
std::map<std::string, std::tuple<SomeUncertainType, AnotherUncertainType>> ref_maps;

// one type 
msgType1 msg1_t; // = ...with some value assigned;
msgType1::SharedPtr msg1_p; //-> ...with some value assigned, and notice, here is a SharedPtr
std::string topic_name1 = "t1";

// another type
msgType2 msg2_t;
msgType2::SharedPtr msg2_p;
std::string topic_name1 = "t2";

ref_maps[t1] = std::make_tuple(msg1_t, msg1_p);
ref_maps[t2] = std::make_tuple(msg2_t, msg2_p);

Is this possible, or is there any other method to implement a similar result?
Are different ros2 msgTypes (and ::SharedPtr) inheriting from some base class so that I can declare ref_maps like:
std::map<std::string, std::tuple<MsgTypeBase, MsgTypePtrBase>> ref_maps;


Looks like a dupe of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21384739/1593077

If it is necessary to use a class whose instance at any given time holds either the value of one type or its alternatives, provided that they are known, the standard solution is std::variant.
It essentially represents a type-safe union, which provides a set of member and non-member functions to make the switch between one type and the other simpler. Furthermore, values are always statically-allocated, avoiding the memory and performance overhead of dynamic allocation.
std::map<std::string, std::pair<std::variant<T1, T2>, std::variant<T1, T2>>>;

If possible couples of types are only (T1, U1), (T2, U2), it is possible to modify the definition in the following way.
std::map<std::string, std::variant<std::pair<T1, U1>, std::pair<T2, U2>>>;

Conversely, if all types are not known, it is possible to use the std::any class.
It describes a type-safe container for single values of any copy-constructible type. However, to achieve this goal, the implementation exploits void pointers and dynamic allocation, leading to a greater memory and performance overhead.
std::map<std::string, std::pair<std::any, std::any>>;

To be more specific, it does not always perform the dynamic allocation, since SBO may be used for small and non-throwing-movable types, but your case seems not to meet these requirements.
